# Java decompress archive file

Tags: java, gzip, java-io, compression, php-ziparchive

I have written below program to extract archive files. Though it works as required, I would like to have your advice on the possible ways to enhance its performance and reduce code complexity or is it possible to achieve the results in a much simpler way.

Also, In the commonExtracter method, instead of creating directories intermittently is it possible to make use of temporary folders to do the same job? The final step should be like creating directory and put the decompressed temp folder inside it.

```
public class ExtractAllArchives {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File archiveFileLocation = new File("C:\\ZIP\\Sample.tar.gz");
//      File archiveFileLocation = new File("C:\\ZIP\\Root.zip");
        File destination = null;

        try {
            destination = new File(archiveFileLocation.getParent() + File.separator
                    + FilenameUtils.getBaseName(archiveFileLocation.getName()));
            if (destination.exists()) {
                FileUtils.deleteDirectory(destination);
            }
            destination.mkdir();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String fileExtn = FilenameUtils.getExtension(archiveFileLocation.getAbsolutePath());
        String outputFolder = destination.getAbsolutePath();
        switch (fileExtn) {
        case "gz":
            try (TarArchiveInputStream ais = new TarArchiveInputStream(
                    new GzipCompressorInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(archiveFileLocation))))) {
                commonExtracter(ArchiveStreamFactory.TAR, ais, outputFolder);
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        case "zip":
            try (ArchiveInputStream ais = new ArchiveStreamFactory().createArchiveInputStream(ArchiveStreamFactory.ZIP,
                    new FileInputStream(archiveFileLocation))) {
                commonExtracter(ArchiveStreamFactory.ZIP, ais, outputFolder);
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("No archive extractor found");
        }
        System.out.println("File extraction completed");
    }

    private static void commonExtracter(String archiveName, ArchiveInputStream ais, String outputFolder) {
        ArchiveEntry entry = null;
        try {
            while ((entry = ais.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                String filePath = outputFolder + File.separator + entry.getName();
                Path fileLoc = Paths.get(filePath);
                if (entry.isDirectory()) {
                    new File(filePath).mkdirs();
                } else {
                    try (OutputStream bos = Files.newOutputStream(fileLoc)) {
                        IOUtils.copy(ais, bos);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("Failed to create the output file");
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

Any help on this topic is much appreciated.

Thank you.
```